# .net core web api Routing ex) 2depth /movies/inception/actors/DiCaprio/

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-routing

[web-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

This sample's routing is 1 depth

req:
/movies/inception/actors/DiCaprio/

res:
json DiCaprio birth, DiCaprio hair color etc....

you want to configure rest api server in 2depth.

/movies/{variable}/actors/{variable}/

/movies/{movie_name}/actors/{actor_name}/

What should I do?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you want to configure rest api server in 2depth.
>
> /movies/{variable}/actors/{variable}/
>
> /movies/{movie_name}/actors/{actor_name}/
>
> What should I do?

You can use the Route attribute or HTTP verb templates to configure the route template and set parameters.

Code like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/movies/{movie_name}/actors/{actor_name}/")]
    public IActionResult GetMovies(string movie_name, string actor_name)
    {
        return Ok($"Movies: {movie_name}, actor name: {actor_name}");  
    }
}
```

Or

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/movies/{movie_name}/actors/{actor_name}/")]
    [HttpGet]
    //[HttpGet("/movies/{movie_name}/actors/{actor_name}/")]
    public IActionResult GetMovies(string movie_name, string actor_name)
    {
        return Ok($"Movies: {movie_name}, actor name: {actor_name}");  
    }
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

More detail information about routing, see [Route templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-templates) and [Attribute routing for REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis).